# Is there a reliable way to tell if my call is blocked by the call recipient?

Tags: call-screening

I want to know if my calls are being blocked by number xxx-xxxxxxxx and if so log the data.

**Is there a reliable way to tell if *my call* is blocked by the call recipient?**

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to tell this information: the target phone could be switched off or unplugged for example.

Comment: The fact that it could be off or unplugged doesn't in any way mean that the network cannot report that the phone was on and reachable but blocked the call.  Or if it's a carrier-level block there's nothing to stop the carrier from reporting the block.  I would suspect that the carriers prevent both of these or at least do nothing to enable it, but that's a different point.

Comment: So is "You won't be able to tell this information" incorrect? Your comment implies "no" but you still downvoted?